# How do I make a txt file editable from batch?

Tags: batch-file, text

So right now, I am trying to figure out how to make a .txt file editable by the user of the batch program. I already have the batch file creating the file, but now I need to make it so the .txt file has what the user answered for the question. Here is what I have now:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to the Space Mapping Discord Report Maker
pause
echo Made by N3ther, version 0.1 ALPHA
pause
@echo off
break>"%userdomain%\%username%\Desktop\report.txt"
echo Question 1: What is your username on Discord?`
```

(It's for a report maker I am moderator on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something like below is what you need:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ReportFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\report.txt"
del "%ReportFile%" 2>nul

echo Welcome to the Space Mapping Discord Report Maker
echo(
echo Made by N3ther, version 0.1 ALPHA
echo(

call :PromptUser 1 "What is your username on Discord?"
call :PromptUser 2 "What is ...?"

rem Restore saved environment and exit batch processing.
endlocal
exit /B

rem This small subroutine prompts the user for an input until something is
rem entered at all and then appends the entered input to the report file.

:PromptUser
set "Input="
:PromptAgain
set /P "Input=Question %~1: %~2 "
rem Has the user entered anything at all?
if not defined Input goto PromptAgain
echo !Input!>>"%ReportFile%"
goto :EOF
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) and the Wikipedia article about [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).